# vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties Throwing mysterious error code

Tags: c++, graphics, gpu, vulkan

I wa following this [vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Presentation/Swap_chain) and reached the swap chain part.

I copy pasted the section about modifying the checkDeviceExtensionProperties, which got me this function:

```
//globally declared at the top of the file
const std::vector<const char*> deviceExtensions = {
    VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME
}; 

/* code */

bool checkDeviceExtensionSupport(VkPhysicalDevice pDevice) {
    uint32_t extensionCount;
    vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties(pDevice, nullptr, &extensionCount, nullptr);

    std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> availableExtensions(extensionCount);
    vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties(pDevice, nullptr, &extensionCount, availableExtensions.data());

   /* std::set<std::string> requiredExtensions(deviceExtensions.begin(), deviceExtensions.end());

    for (const auto& extension : availableExtensions) {
        requiredExtensions.erase(extension.extensionName);
    }*/

    return true;//requiredExtensions.empty();
}
```

When I uncomment the function `vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties` an error is thrown.

The error code returned by the debug callback (i.e the bit of `VkDebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagBitsEXT`) is 0b10000. Which is none of the bits  defined in `vulkan_core.h`.

Any suggestion as to what I could be messing up?

Edit:

The output from the debug message is:

```
[...]
validation layer: Device Extension: VK_KHR_device_group (libGLX_nvidia.so.0) version 0.0.3
Loader Message
16
validation layer: Device Extension: VK_KHR_draw_indirect_count (libGLX_nvidia.so.0) version 0.0.1
Loader Message
16
validation layer: Device Extension: VK_KHR_driver_properties (libGLX_nvidia.so.0) version 0.0.1
Loader Message
16
validation layer: Device Extension: VK_KHR_external_fence (libGLX_nvidia.so.0) version 0.0.1
Loader Message
16
validation layer: Device Extension: VK_KHR_external_fence_fd (libGLX_nvidia.so.0) version 0.0.1
Loader Message
16
validation layer: Device Extension: VK_KHR_external_memory (libGLX_nvidia.so.0) version 0.0.1
Loader Message
16
validation layer: Device Extension: VK_KHR_external_memory_fd (libGLX_nvidia.so.0) version 0.0.1
Loader Message
16
validation layer: Device Extension: VK_KHR_external_semaphore (libGLX_nvidia.so.0) version 0.0.1
Loader Message
16
validation layer: Device Extension: VK_KHR_external_semaphore_fd (libGLX_nvidia.so.0) version 0.0.1
Loader Message
16
validation layer: Device Extension: VK_KHR_get_memory_requirements2 (libGLX_nvidia.so.0) version 0.0.1
Loader Message
16
validation layer: Device Extension: VK_KHR_image_format_list (libGLX_nvidia.so.0) version 0.0.1
[...]
```

The debug callback is:

```
static VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL debugCallback(
    VkDebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagBitsEXT messageSeverity,
    VkDebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT messageType,
    const VkDebugUtilsMessengerCallbackDataEXT* pCallbackData,
    void* pUserData) {

    std::cerr << "validation layer: " << pCallbackData->pMessage << std::endl;
    cout << pCallbackData->pMessageIdName << endl;
    cout << messageSeverity << endl;

    if (messageSeverity >= VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_WARNING_BIT_EXT) {
        // Message is important enough to show
    }


    return VK_FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Well, what's the `pMessage` of the callback anyway?

Comment: The message is is just the name and version of each extension.

I will paste output here when I have access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0b10000` is `VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_INFO_BIT_EXT`. Just filter `INFO` messages when you create the callback with `vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT`.

Comment: If it's just INFO severity, does that mena that no error is ctually occurring? I am just getting notified of an event?

Comment: Exactly, you can safely ignore events of this type. They only contain info that may be helpful when debugging stuff.

Comment: `VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_INFO_BIT_EXT` and `VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_VERBOSE_BIT_EXT` are just informative. Disable them at messenger creation unless you are digging for some info.